# linux: sigwait() takes precedence over pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK)?

Tags: linux, multithreading, signals

In a program, SIGCHLD is blocked from main thread, then

1. thread "THREAD_1" is doing sigwait(),
2. thread "THREAD_2" which forks a child process and kills it, in this thread I called pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, 0) to unblock SIGCHLD before killing the child.

But SIGCHLD is still being picked up by sigwait().

Other than unblock SIGCHLD from main() before creating threads, is there a way to make SIGCHLD bypass sigwait() ? I do not want sigwait() to handle SIGCHILD.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is permissible per [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html):

> Signals generated for the process shall be delivered to exactly one of those threads within the process which [thread] is in a call to a sigwait() function selecting that signal ***or*** [which thread] has not blocked delivery of the signal.

(Emphasis added.)

Simply remove SIGCHLD from the waiting thread's selection mask and the program will do what you want.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. unfortunately i can not change the code of the thread doing sigwait()

Comment: Can you change the forking thread?  You could set up a pipe or socketpair, fork a little wrapper program which runs the program you want to run, and then have that wrapper write the exit code of its child back to your thread.  This presumes that the sigwaiting thread will harmlessly discard a SIGCHLD is wasn't expecting.  If not, you'll need more extravagant solutions.

Comment: @wei If you do not have control over a thread, you need to isolate it to its own process. It is an absolute requirement that all the threads in a process cooperate in the handling of process-level resources like memory, signals, and file descriptors. A non-cooperating thread is intolerable and should be quarantined.

Comment: @pilcrow Thanks, i will try that. Another work around I could think of is to interpose sigwait(), remove sigchld from the sigset then call downstream(glibc) sigwait()

Comment: I suggest you hold off on interposing your own sigwait() — that's hack might just take you through the looking glass.  @DavidSchwartz is right in that you're in a very unenviable position.